# Angular library is not updating its variable back

Tags: angular

I have created a library that takes input variable type as a string.

**app.componant.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="query" >

<my-lib [query] ="query"></my-lib>
```

**app.componant.ts**

```
export class Query {
  query: string=""
}
```

In my-lib I have an input box that takes query as ngModel whenever I update query in-app it gets reflected to my-lib. But whenever I update the query in the library it won't update back.
Can anyone tell me how I can update value of query in app?

Comment: Use two way binding in ngModel as `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: @SagarV I have bind it in the textbox as  [(ngModel)] please check question.

Comment: Create a stackblitz example

Comment: Thanks, @SagarV. but MoxxiManagarm posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2-way-data-binding.

**1st step:**

add `()` to the html tag

```
<my-lib [(query)]="query"></my-lib>
```

**2nd step:**

add an EventEmitter to notify the change back, the name is important, must be the input name concatinated with `Change`, so in your case `queryChange`.

```
export class MyLibComponent {
  @Input() query: string;
  @Output() queryChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

**3rd recommended step:**

To not call queryChange manually every time query was updated, it is recommended to use getter and setter.

```
export class MyLibComponent {
  private _query: string;

  @Input()
  set query(value: string) {
    this._query = value;
    this.queryChange.emit(value);
  }
  get query(): string{
    return this._query;
  }

  @Output() queryChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

Comment: I have used two-way binding first step that you mentioned but it did not work. Do I need to use all two steps?

Comment: You need step 1 + 2. The EventEmitter needs to emit the change. Either call it manually or use the setter as recommended in step 3. You could read further here: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Comment: I am getting Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on seter and getter of query.